# How tolimit the length of drop down list displayed by AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

In an application I need to limit the length of drop down list displayed by AutoCompleteTextView in android to let the below buttons be visible.Can anyone help me in limiting the length of drop down list programmatically.

Comment: Well what i actually need is that each time a user selects some value(or say a email) I add a comma to the value (similar to your email's TO field) & then I have a comma separated value(eg abc@gmail.com,) after that dropdown is immediately visible hiding send & cancel button .So I need to enable threshold limit to 1 again how to do so??Any solutions??

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Resolved:
Hi I used MultiAutoCompleteTextView instead of AutoCompleteTextView and that solved my problem.

Thanks stackoverflow

Comment: It is better to explain the solution in detail